# UIWebView Swipe does not work with Voice Over on

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swipe, voiceover

I am using a web view to render pages, my web view runs fine with voice over off but when i turn it on double taps works, single finger swipe works but three finger swipe is not working even four finger swipe works for switching apps. Can I get some help on this. I added UISwipeGestureRecognizer and the funny thing is gestureRecognizer is not even called when voice over is on for swipe but works fine with voice over off

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(swipeRightAction:)];
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [myWebView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
    swipeRight.delegate = self;

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeftAction:)];
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [myWebView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
    swipeLeft.delegate = self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"anypage" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@""] isDirectory:NO]]];
     myWebView.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)swipeRightAction:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeRight
{
    NSLog(@"Swiped in Right Direction");
    [self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"anyJSFunction();"];
}

- (void)swipeLeftAction:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeLeft
{
    NSLog(@"Swiped in Left Direction");
    [self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"anyJSFunction();"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved. Accessibility Scroll needed to be added. Thanks everyone.

```
- (BOOL)accessibilityScroll:(UIAccessibilityScrollDirection)direction
{
    NSLog(@"Accessibility Scroll Captured");
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: very nice, but what else is needed to capture the direction and act upon this accessibility scroll event?